# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo : InstantiationException

Tags: java, android

I am getting the following error. Please help me solving it.

```
06-13 13:08:00.214: E/AndroidRuntime(549): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-13 13:08:00.214: E/AndroidRuntime(549): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.redial/com.redial.PopupDialogActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.redial.PopupDialogActivity
06-13 13:08:00.214: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
06-13 13:08:00.214: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-13 13:08:00.214: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-13 13:08:00.214: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-13 13:08:00.214: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-13 13:08:00.214: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-13 13:08:00.214: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-13 13:08:00.214: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 13:08:00.214: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-13 13:08:00.214: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-13 13:08:00.214: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-13 13:08:00.214: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-13 13:08:00.214: E/AndroidRuntime(549): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.redial.PopupDialogActivity
06-13 13:08:00.214: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-13 13:08:00.214: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
06-13 13:08:00.214: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
06-13 13:08:00.214: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.
```

Comment: How are you instantiating the Activity?

Comment: Add the Constructor you have for PopupDialogActivity

Comment: I get the impression that you didn't post the whole stack trace. Can you add the remaining lines?

Comment: freinds it was due to context that i was passing i just changed context to getBAseContext